# how to create a multi column list with css?

Tags: css

I want to create a fixed layout that displays some images. for example, a "table" of 3 images in a row and 3 images in a column.
Also i need that every li conatins some fixed width and height and the image centered and alignet to top.

So i've thinked in something like this:

```
<ul>
<li><img /></li>
<li><img /></li>
<li><img /></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li><img /></li>
<li><img /></li>
<li><img /></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li><img /></li>
<li><img /></li>
<li><img /></li>
</ul>
```

But i don't know css, still i've created some like this but still doesn't work...

```
ul {display: block; text-align: center; border:#666666 solid 1px; height: 150px; padding:0; margin:0;}
li { list-style:none; float:left; width: 150px; height: 150px; margin-bottom: 32px;}
```

---

Fixed version:

```
ul{ height: 180px; text-align:center;padding:0;}
li{list-style:none;padding:0;width: 25%;height: 180px;float: left; display:inline-block;}
```

Note: Only works for only one `<ul>` with many `<li>`, the columns are setted changing the width of the `<li>`. 25% means 4 columns, 33% = 3 columns, etc. Formula: 100/(desired columns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made 3x3 box with list tag and uploaded [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?zgmzydnzyzz), hope it help you Sein.

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul { list-style-type:none; margin:0px; padding:0px; overflow:hidden; }
    li { float:left; width:150px; height:150px; margin:2px; padding:3px; background:#CCCCCC; text-align:center; }
    li img { max-width:144px; }
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="" /></li>
    <li><img src="" /></li>
    <li><img src="" /></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><img src="" /></li>
    <li><img src="" /></li>
    <li><img src="" /></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><img src="" /></li>
    <li><img src="" /></li>
    <li><img src="" /></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there Sein.  All I did to make it work was removed the `float: left;` and replaced it with `display: inline-block;` on the `<li>` tag.  That lined everything up perfectly for me.  If you have any issues with the vertical alignment, try setting the following on the `<img>` tags: `vertical-align: top;`

There is a phenomenal article on the Mozilla WebDev blog for addressing this: [Cross-Browser Inline-Block](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/)

Comment: Yep, but inline-block don't allows to set height :P

But well, i've solved that. Fixed on the main post.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#inlineblock - "An inline block is placed inline (ie. on the same line as adjacent content), but it behaves as a block."  Behaving like a block means you can set a specific height and width, I do it all the time with horizontal navigation menus.